# JAVA: data for Setup A won't be displayed because my three stored procs couldn't get called

Tags: java

I have two setups namely Setup A and Setup B. Each setup has its own controller having the same three initializeBillingInvoice methods. These are `initializeBillingInvoice(), initializeBillingInvoiceBreakdown()` and `initializeBillingInvoiceAdjustment()`.

The difference between the two controllers is, `computeTotal()` method.

 **For Setup A**, it computes **billing invoice breakdown** such as total OT, total RH, total SH and total Reg Hol, and **billing invoice adjustment** if not empty.

 **For Setup B**, it only computes **billing invoice adjustment** if not empty.

The problem is with **Setup A**. It won't display all billing invoice data because Setup A Controller won't call my three stored procedures. These are, `cmr_get_billinginvoicebreakdown_by_billinginvoiceid,
cmr_get_billinginvoice_template_details,`
and `cmr_get_billinginvoiceadjustment`. 

 Unlike **Setup B**, it's working fine. Setup B Controller calls my three stored procedures.

I'm confused. Please help. Thank you very much.

[image]

GlassFish Server 4.1 Logs
[image]

MySQL
[image]

Here's my Code (Using Java 8)

```
/*GETTERS-SETTERS*/

/*METHODS*/
public SetupAVatExBothController() {
        try {        
            Map<String, String> parameter = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            billingInvoiceId = Integer.parseInt(parameter.get("billingInvoiceId"));


        initializeBillingInvoice();
        initializeBillingInvoiceBreakdown();
        initializeBillingInvoiceAdjustment();
        computeTotal();

        String invoiceStartDate = DateFormatUtils.format(billingInvoice.getProcessDateFrom(), "MMMM dd");
        String invoiceEndDate = DateFormatUtils.format(billingInvoice.getProcessDateTo(), "dd, yyyy");
        period = invoiceStartDate + "-" + invoiceEndDate;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SetupAVatExBothController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

}

private void initializeBillingInvoice() {
    try{
        billingInvoiceDAOAssembler = new BillingInvoiceDAOAssembler();
        billingInvoice = new BillingInvoice();
        billingInvoice.setBillingInvoiceId(billingInvoiceId);
        billingInvoice = billingInvoiceDAOAssembler.getBillingInvoiceTemplateInformation(dbConnection, billingInvoice);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SetupAVatExBothController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}

private void initializeBillingInvoiceBreakdown() {
    try{
        BillingInvoiceBreakDownDAOAssembler billingInvoiceBreakDownDAOAssembler = new BillingInvoiceBreakDownDAOAssembler();
        billingInvoiceBreakdown = new BillingInvoiceBreakdown();
        billingInvoiceBreakdown.setBillingInvoiceId(billingInvoiceId);
        billingInvoiceBreakdown = billingInvoiceBreakDownDAOAssembler.getBillingInvoiceBreakdown(dbConnection, billingInvoiceBreakdown);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SetupAVatExBothController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}

private void initializeBillingInvoiceAdjustment() {
    try{
        BillingInvoiceAdjustmentDAOAssembler billingInvoiceAdjustmentDAOAssembler = new BillingInvoiceAdjustmentDAOAssembler();
        BillingInvoiceAdjustment billingInvoiceAdjustment = new BillingInvoiceAdjustment();
        billingInvoiceAdjustment.setBillingInvoiceId(billingInvoiceId);
        billingInvoiceAdjustmentTbl = billingInvoiceAdjustmentDAOAssembler.getBillingInvoiceAdjustments(dbConnection, billingInvoiceAdjustment);
        isAdjustmentEmpty = billingInvoiceAdjustmentTbl.isEmpty();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SetupAVatExBothController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}

private void computeTotal() {

    //Billing Invoice Breakdown
    totalRh = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
    totalOt = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
    totalSh = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
    totalRegHol = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);

    totalRh = billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalSgRhFee().add(billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalAfRhFee());
    totalOt = billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalSgOtFee().add(billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalAfOtFee());
    totalSh = billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalSgShFee().add(billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalAfShFee());
    totalRegHol = billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalSgRegHolFee().add(billingInvoiceBreakdown.getTotalAfRegHolFee());

    //Billing Invoice Adjustments
    totalAdjustment = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);        
    if(!isAdjustmentEmpty) {
        billingInvoiceAdjustmentTbl.forEach((adjustment) -> {
            if(adjustment.getOperation()) { totalAdjustment = totalAdjustment.add(adjustment.getInvoiceAdjustmentAmt()); } 
            else { totalAdjustment = totalAdjustment.subtract(adjustment.getInvoiceAdjustmentAmt()); }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Sorry late response. It's working now. I don't get it why but it's weird. Thanks.